# Isomorphic Coxeter groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups, symmetry

After enumerating the spherical Coxeter groups, it is easy to see that no two distinct cases are isomorphic. Does the same hold for Euclidean and hyperbolic Coxeter groups?

Comment: What precisely does "no two distinct cases are isomorphic" mean?

Comment: Even for finite (spherical, as you say) Coxeter groups, two different Coxeter systems may produce groups which are isomorphic as abstract groups. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2924244/coxeter-systems-and-number-of-generators

Comment: It means that two Coxeter groups which describe the same arrangement of mirrors, such as $A_3$ and $D_3$, are considered the same.

Comment: But is the isomorphism as abstract groups?

Comment: Yes, the isomorphism is as abstract groups.

Comment: Then, the answer is as I explained above- it is not true even for finite groups that two different Coxeter systems produce non-isomorphic groups.

Comment: Ah, I see. $G_2 \cong E_3$.

Comment: Anyways if you google "the isomorphism problem for Coxeter groups" you will find a lot about the question of algorithmically determining when two Coxeter matrices yield isomorphic groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119870/discussion-between-daniel-sebald-and-sam-hopkins).